# Mysql - help for scheduling constraints

Tags: mysql

I am inputting schedules in my vb program and storing it in mysql, and if my entered data is conflicting with the records in db, it should not be able to store it.

NOTE: I'm checking conflict using the SELECT FROM query. if it search something in db, then it wont store it.

ex. I have in my db this record

```
| day | tstart | tend | class | room | teacher_id | subject |
| M   | 6:00   | 7:00 | 1A    | 101  | 0001       | ENGL1   |
```

Now if I enter (e.g.)

```
M - 6:00 - 7:00 - 1A - 102 - 0001 - ENGL1
```

it stores it in db, which it shouldn't, anyone can help me with the constraints?

-no same teacher should be teaching at the same time

this is the select query that I'm using

```
"SELECT * FROM tbl_schedule WHERE (day='" & day(getDay) & "' AND time_start='" & timeStart & "' AND room_no='" & roomlist(roomNumber) & "') OR (day='" & day(getDay) & "' AND time_start='" & timeStart & "' AND room_no='" & roomlist(roomNumber) & "' AND teacher_id='" & teacherlist(tId) & "')"
```

EDIT: Dont mind the column name in the example and in my code, I just made it shorter, Also, class and rooms are always different so I did not put it in the query (automated scheduling)

EDIT2: If there's a row fetched using the query, it should not store the data in db, if there's nothing fetched, it will store.

Answer (score 0):

Set a `UNIQUE` constraint or `KEY` on the fields that together would constitute a conflict, that will stop data being added with it clashes with existing data.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html for full details.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    col1 INT NOT NULL,
    col2 INT NOT NULL,
    col3 INT NOT NULL,
    col4 INT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY (col1, col2)
)

> INSERT INTO t1 set col1='1', col2='2', col3='3', col4='4';
data inserted

> INSERT INTO t1 set col1='3', col2='2', col3='3', col4='4';
data inserted

> INSERT INTO t1 set col1='1', col2='2', col3='5', col4='6';
not inserted - entry with col1=1, col2=2 already exists
```